# How to get a result from multiple select statements with pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Basically, I have the following example (Assume cur comes from a valid connection):

```
>>> con =  pymysql.connect(<parameters go here>)
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> sql = "SELECT @a := 0; SELECT @a := @a+2; SELECT @a;"
>>> res = cur.execute(sql)
>>> res
1
```

As you can see, `res` returns the integer 1, which means the `sql` went well. However, the last select should return the number 2 and I need that number.

If I run this code (suggested by @falsetru), I don't get what I need either:

```
>>> cur.execute(sql)
1
>>> cur.fetchall()
[{u'@a := 0': 0}]
```

How can I retrieve it? Is it possible without separating the SQL statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Cursor.fetchone`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) to get a single row, or [`Cursor.fetchmany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchmany)/[`Cursor.fetchall`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall) to get many or all result rows.

```
row = cur.fetchone()
a = row[0]
```

---

**UPDATE** `Cursor.execute` executes a single sql statement, so execute statements separately (by spliting `sql` by `;`)

```
import pymysql
con =  pymysql.connect(user='root', password='root')
cur = con.cursor()
sql = "SELECT @a := 0; SELECT @a := @a+2; SELECT @a;"
for stmt in sql.split(';'):
    if stmt.strip():
        cur.execute(stmt)
row = cur.fetchone()
a = row[0]
print(a)  # => 2
```

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that was my only option. In any case, for those looking here, IF, and only IF you have to execute the same statement multiple times (which was not my case), you could take a look at `cursor.executemany`