# Change mysql session mode and run group by queries in a single pymysql execute

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

It has been driving me crazy today.  In one of the developing environments, the MySQL is 5.7 where:

`sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`

is the default.

I cannot find an easy way to do `sql_mode = '';` in pymysql since each execute only allows 1 query. If I do the following:

```
import pymysql as dbapi

dbServer=SERVER_NAME

dbPass=PASSWORD

dbUser=USER_NAME

db=dbapi.connect(host=dbServer,user=dbUser,passwd=dbPass)

cur=db.cursor()

    CY_QUERY_2 = (

        "SET SESSION sql_mode='';"+

        "SELECT *'" +

        " FROM table" + 

        "' GROUP BY PROPERTY_ID, YEAR;")

    cur.execute(CY_QUERY_2)

    cy_result2 = cur.fetchall()
```

We will get an error:

> There is an error in your MySQL syntax near  "SET SESSION sql_mode=''; SELECT * FROM table

Sadly, we have hundreds of columns for each table which the code processes. Listing hundreds of columns in each query is not a good practice.  Can any guru enlighten?  Thanks.

Comment: you have typos: `"SELECT *'" +` instead of `"SELECT *" +` and `"' GROUP BY PROPERTY_ID, YEAR;"` instead of `" GROUP BY PROPERTY_ID, YEAR;"`

Comment: maybe this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41787195/6779252

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the 2 queries separately (pseudocode):

```
q1 = "SET SESSION sql_mode=''; "
s2 = "select ..... ;"
cur.execute(q1)
cur.execute(q1)
read_cursor_here....
```